# Is it possible to access session value from iframe in php

Tags: php, iframe, session-variables

hi
Is it possible to access session value from iframe. Both sites hosted on the same domain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing sessions variables through an iframe, php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965862/passing-sessions-variables-through-an-iframe-php)

Comment: Search and you shall find. You need to start the session in both scripts, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are same domain, browsers *should* send the session cookie to both requests, so yes. =)

Comment: Not always, for example in IE your must send this headers `P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"`