# Passing $_SESSION through an iframe - PHP

Tags: php, session, iframe, session-variables

For the record, I DID see this entry - [Passing sessions variables through an iframe, php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965862/passing-sessions-variables-through-an-iframe-php) which is asking the exact same question, but the answer (even when I followed it to a T) still isn't working for me.

I have two pages - one is the landing page, the other is the page pulled in to the landing page via iframe. I start the session on the landing page and assigned $_SESSION a value, and I want that value pulled in to the iframe.

Here's my code for the landing page:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['vendorname'] = $this->getVendorId(); // store session vendor name data
    echo "Vendor = ". $_SESSION['vendorname']; // test to see if the vendor name was properly set
session_write_close();
?>

<html>
  <body>
    ....blah blah...
    <iframe width="100%" src="http://www.somewhere.com/iframe.php"></iframe>
  <body>
</html>
```

Here's the code from the page within the iframe:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>  

<html> 
  <head>   
    <link href="css/something.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
  </head>

 <body>
  <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['vendorname']) && is_array($_SESSION['vendorname'])) {
       echo "vendor = ". $_SESSION['vendorname']; }
     else {
       echo "Meh, back to the drawing board"; }?>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

On the landing page, the `$_SESSION` displays correctly. It retrieves the vendor's name via our database and spits it out on the screen. In the iframe however, it only displays my failure message ("Meh, back to the drawing board"). I am missing something. :(

**EDIT:**

Per Marc B's suggestion, I'm now checking the session_id(). So for this code (on landing page):

```
<?php
session_start();
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>"; 
    $_SESSION['vendorname'] = $this->getVendorId(); // store session vendor name data
    echo "Vendor = ". $_SESSION['vendorname']; //test to see if the vendorname was properly set
    echo "<br>";
    echo session_id();
session_write_close();
?>
```

I'm getting the following output:

**0lq5gb79p52plgd9mcknpife60
Vendor = SUPERVEND
0lq5gb79p52plgd9mcknpife60**

On the iframe page, for this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>  

<html> 
      <head>   
        <link href="css/something.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
      </head>

     <body>
<?php
echo session_id();
if(isset($_SESSION['vendorname'])) {
    echo "vendor = ". $_SESSION['vendorname']; }
else {
    echo "vendor = ". $_SESSION['vendorname']; }
?>
```

I'm getting the following output:

**0lq5gb79p52plgd9mcknpife60 
0lq5gb79p52plgd9mcknpife60
vendor =**

Comment: check that `session_id()` has the SAME value in both pages. If it doesn't, then your session cookies aren't being set properly.

Comment: Okay, here's a stupid/novice question.... how do I do that?

Comment: `session_start(); echo session_id();` in both scripts. the value that's displayed SHOULD be the same, and should match what's in your PHPSESSID cookie (or whatever its name happens to be) in your browser. If the value changes, then you've got multiple sessions in place, and the one where you saved those values is getting "lost".

Comment: Thanks! So, the session_id() is the same across the board. I checked it before and after $_SESSION['vendorname'] was set AND within the iframe. ...so, do you have any other ideas why this is messing up? :( Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Start the iframe with the following:

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
session_start();
```

you should then be able to access the session variables in the normal fashion.

Comment: Can you explain what this does?